# When Anchor URL is visible then change anchor class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I was takeing a peek at stackoverflowe for very long time and now it happend - have to first time ask a question, so here it is:

I've got page with anchor menu sticked to browser top (so its always visible and so on),
the point is that I'm trying to make the active (visible content of this one) anchor another color than those non-active.

For example I have a menu with links (menu1, menu2)
And Conent of menu1, and Content of menu2.
When I see content of menu1, the link "menu1" is green, menu2 is red
when I see content of menu2, the link "menu2" is green, menu1 is red

I hope its clear.

I tried with jqueryinview but I don't full understand it,
as far as I understand this globaly it should work like that:
when browser see classA
then add classB to classC

where classA is content, classB is style for "active" anchor in menu, classC is anchor in menu.

I would really apreciate some help.

Comment: It's not clear. Please add the related HTML + CSS.

Comment: I think you are looking for that plug-in : http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Just to make sure, your talking about anchors such as `www.somesite.com#menu1`?

Comment: yes, something like www.somesite.com#menu1
this is fiddle for this, simple but i dont know how to explain this easier http://jsfiddle.net/9uB4Y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery inview is a good solution for your case. What you need is a js code that calculates the top offset for the content element versus the top window offset. If it is approximate, then you add the active class to the relative menu.

Check https://github.com/zuk/jquery.inview , I'm using it with jQuery 1.10, it works just fine.
Basic usage is:

```
$(el).on("inview", function(ev,visible){
        if (visible) 
            something();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the flawless way I have always used jQuery to highlight the current menu item

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
});
```

With DOM ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
      var url = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      $('[href$="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey it's almost it, but i dont know why it adds this active class only when site is refreshed, but whitout this nothing happens...

Comment: That's to do with running it DOM ready. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Youre very kind to help me, but i still get result only on site refresh (class active adds after site refresh)

Comment: Where in the HTML are you putting the script? it should be just before the closing `body` tag